# My R code and API call is giving me different results in two different sets of code

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm working on updating some legacy code that is pulling data for prices and using the `quantmod` package to calculate a daily return, standard deviation, bi-weekly return (10 days), and a bi-weekly standard deviation. The new API call is correctly pulling in the same values for the ID I'm looking at compared to the old method. However, when I replicate the same `Delt()` and `sd` functions, the results are different and I'm not able to see why. Here is the code I'm running:

```
#### Legacy code ####
AllPrices <- F.ExtractFormulaHistory(master, StringA, StringB);
for(i in 1:length(master)){
  Prices <- AllPrices[AllPrices$Id == master[i],];
  Prices <- Prices[is.na(Prices$fg.price) == FALSE,];
  if (length(Prices$fg.price) > 252) {
##    print(i);
    Prices$DailyRet <- Delt(Prices$fg.price);
    Prices$DailySD <- rollapply(Prices$DailyRet, width = 252, FUN = sd, fill = NA, align = "right") * sqrt(252);
    Prices$BiWeeklyRet <- Delt(Prices$fg.price, k = 10);
    Prices$BiWeeklySD <- rollapply(Prices$BiWeeklyRet, width = 252, FUN = sd, fill = NA, align = "right") * sqrt(25.2);
    
    write.table(Prices, file = MPTempFN, append = TRUE, sep = ",", col.names = FALSE, row.names = TRUE, qmethod = "double");
  }
}

### My code, note i needed to invert the price of DailyRet as it was giving me the opposite of what 
### I was looking for. 
## Extract Price, ID, and Date columns
ID <- AllPrices$requestId
Price <- AllPrices$P_PRICE.0..400.D.
Date <- as.Date(AllPrices$date)

## Calculate daily returns
DailyRet <- (Delt(Price, k = 1)) * -1

## Calculate rolling 252-day standard deviation of daily returns
DailySD <- rollapply(DailyRet, width = 252, FUN = sd, fill = NA, align = "right") * sqrt(252)

## Calculate bi-weekly returns
BiWeeklyRet <- Delt(Price, k = 10)

## Calculate rolling 252-day standard deviation of bi-weekly returns
BiWeeklySD <- rollapply(BiWeeklyRet, width = 252, FUN = sd, fill = NA, align = "right") * sqrt(25.2)

## Combine results into a data frame
Prices <- data.frame(ID, Date, Price, DailyRet, DailySD, BiWeeklyRet, BiWeeklySD)
colnames(Prices) <- c("ID", "Date","Price", "DailyRet", "DailySD", "BiWeeklyRet", "BiWeeklySD")
Prices$Date <- Date

## Save results to a CSV file
write.csv(Prices, file = "Prices.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

I've included the results that I'm writing to a csv and manually checking to see if my new code is working correctly.

[My code results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nqxs.png), the daily ret is calculating right, however the values are offset by one row which I need to fix.

[Old Legacy code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIVK0.png) that is calculating all the delt/sd functions correctly

I have tried to replicate as closely as I can the old format of the code. Making sure that first, my prices values were correct, and second that there wasn't an issue there. I am able to reproduce the daily return function but my bi-weekly and standard deviations continue to be off.

Comment: Please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - and [these](https://xkcd.com/2116/).